# ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT while inslall React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

i tryed inslall React ussing  `npx create-react-app`

but i was get error:

```
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cosmiconfig: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zxc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-22T18_42_18_021Z-debug-0.log
```

how i can install React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a issue with your network connection or the npm api. 
Although if you could fix it, I would suggest to not use `create-react-app`.
If you want to bootstrap a React app fast, you can use Vite instead. 
CRA is kind of outdated at this moment and can have problems, and Vite is a faster & a more reliable tool.

You can create a React app with Vite using the following command:

```bash
npm create vite app-name -- --template react
```